# How can I design a windows form to be used dynamically on selection in treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, treeview

I'm fairly new to C# programming but I'll explain what it is I'm trying to do.

I have a windows form with a Split Container.  On the left I have a tree view with several nodes which when clicked, should show a completely different view on the right hand side.  For instance, there will be a Computer node which will show a list of computers and a Configuration node which will show a different type of page.

**My question:**  is there a way to design the content of the various right hand side forms, to be swapped in dynamically when the treenode is clicked?  When I say design, I mean actually using the GUI to design each type of view which could appear on the right as opposed to creating it in code.

Thanks,

Comment: Panels or tabs would be my suggestion.  I personally go for tabs so you can switch between them in the GUI easier.  Then just hide the tabs at runtime.  I'd be very interested in a better method though as I feel this is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Thanks - if I were using a tabbed format I would, but the split view is essential to what I'm trying to do. Using tabs wouldn't work here because I need to select a treeview node in order to determine what content is shown on the right - but I DO need the treeview for later in the development.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me - use tabs to design it but hide the tabs at runtime and change the tab to the relevant page when the user clicks a tree node.

Comment: Yes you can design all the views separately as User Controls and add them to your code. See Gjallar's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a `UserControl` that will contain one of your `views` for one type of node.

When a node of this type is clicked you can assign this usercontrol to the right hand side of your form.

When another node is clicked you can simply use a different usercontrol.

How this usercontrol looks can be completely designed in the WinForms GUI designer.

More information about user controls can be found on the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol).

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was talking about.  Will give it a shot and get back to this later on.

Comment: Just for completeness, UserControls are the way forward to accomplish this.  After a quick test, I got pages loading both in advance and 'on demand' based on the tree node.  Thanks for the post.